# Change cell background colour dependent on dropdown

Tags: vba, excel

Complete VBA/Excel beginner here...

I am trying to get the background colour of a cell to change dependent on which dropdown choice was chosen in that cell but I am getting a type match error at the intersect statement. Could someone explain to me why please?

Code as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("C6:G14")

If Intersect(Target, myRange) Then
    MsgBox "Success"
Select Case Target.Value
    Case "YES"
        mycolor = "#84ff84"
    Case "NO"
        mycolor = "#fc3c3c"
    Case Else
        mycolor = xlNone
End Select


End If


Target.Interior.ColorIndex = mycolor


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C6:G14")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Did the trick, cheers. Can I ask why it was not working with intersect?